# How to release memory under following situation?

Tags: macos, memory-leaks, core-graphics

Below is some core graphics code..

```
        CGColorRef colorRefArray[MAGIC_NUM];

        for (int i = 0; i < MAGIC_NUM ; i++)
        {
           ...

           colorRefArray[i] = CreateColor(colorValueForEachColor, numberofcomp);                
        }
```

colorRefArray already has memory and CreateColor(); will again create a memory and it leads to memory leak.

How do I avoid this situation?

One possible thought I have is

```
            CGColorRef colorRefArray[MAGIC_NUM];

            for (int i = 0; i < MAGIC_NUM ; i++)
            {
               ...
               CGColorRef colorref = CreateColor(colorValueForEachColor, numberofcomp);
               colorRefArray[i] = colorref;
               CFRelease(colorref);

            }
```

Is this approach correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it's not. You're immediately releasing the color you created. The correct approach would be this:

```
 CGColorRef colorRefArray[MAGIC_NUM];
 for (int i = 0; i < MAGIC_NUM ; i++)
 {
     ...
    colorRefArray[i] = CreateColor(colorValueForEachColor, numberofcomp);                
 }
 //Use your colors
 //Now release them
 for (int i = 0; i < MAGIC_NUM ; i++)
 {
    CFRelease(colorRefArray[i]);
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

No, because then `colorRefArray` will be filled with invalid pointers.

Try using a `CFMutableArray` instead of a raw C array. Then you only have to worry about the reference to the array, as it will own the colours for you:

```
CFArrayRef CopyColorArray(void) {
    CFMutableArrayRef colorRefArray = CFArrayCreateMutable(NULL, 0, &kCFTypeArrayCallBacks);
    if (colorRefArray) {
        for (int i = 0; i < MAGIC_NUM ; i++) {
            ...
            CGColorRef colorref = CreateColor(colorValueForEachColor, numberofcomp);
            if (colorref) {
                CFArrayAppendValue(colorRefArray, colorref);
                CFRelease(colorref);
            }
        }
    }

    return colorRefArray;
}
```